# PHP 2 dimensional array: To make user input 2 subtract user input 1 based on values from 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

I have to create a PHP application that calculates the population difference between two USA census years. The census year and population will be stored in a two dimensional array. The application should calculate the difference in population and display that difference. If the difference is negative, display a message that reflects the population decreased. If the difference is positive, display a message that indicates the population increased. If no change in population, then display a message that says no population change. This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
        <form action="handle_census.php" method="post">
            <p>Year 1: <input type="number" name="value1" step="10"  min= "1790" max= "2010" size="5"></p>
            <p>Year 2: <input type="number" name="value2" step="10"  min= "1790" max= "2010" size="5"></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That handles the user inputs where the year starts from 1790 and the max is 2010. The user chooses a year and the PHP post handles the calculation. This is where its not working for me:

```
<?php 
$yearList1 = $_POST['value1'];
$yearList2 = $_POST['value2'];

$yearList1 = array(
    array("1790", 3929214),
    array("1800", 5236631),
    array("1810", 7239881),

$yearList2 = array(
    array("1790", 3929214),
    array("1800", 5236631),
    array("1810", 7239881),

$yearTotal = $yearList2 - $yearList1;

print $yearTotal;
?>
```

For simplicity I didn't add in all the years here, but I get an error in the line containing `$yearTotal = $yearList2 - $yearList1;`.

So when the user picks a year, it should recognize it by the number associated with the year.  So for instance if they choose 1790 and 1800, then 1800 should subtract 1790, but not the actual year, the number associated with that year as follows:  5236631 - 3929214 and the answer should be 1307417
Is there something wrong with the way I'm associating the years with the numbers?

Comment: You can't multiply two arrays together. It gives a fatal error "Unsupported operand types." If you're not seeing errors as you're running this code, there's something wrong with your development environment. Code with `display_errors=on`.

Comment: You should probably be using associative arrays, not 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @amphetamachine sorry, i corrected it, its not " * " its subtraction " - "

Comment: @Barmar i edited my post for clarification

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi Arithmetic on arrays is not distributed to the elements. You can use `+` and it appends the arrays, no other arithmetic is allowed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are same-named so it's definitely not going to work. That means you are multiplying arrays and all kinds of things here. Presumably you are trying to do something like:

```
<?php
# First check these are submitted
if(!empty($_POST['value1']) && !empty($_POST['value2'])) {
    # Assign years (you probably want to trim() and check is_numeric() here)
    $year_1 = $_POST['value1'];
    $year_2 = $_POST['value2'];
    # Presumably these are hardcoded otherwise you would isolate using a query
    # instead of grabbing all this list in one giant array
    $years = array(
        array("1790", 3929214),
        array("1800", 5236631),
        array("1810", 7239881)
    );
    # Set defaults here
    $y1 =
    $y2 = 0;
    # Loop first array to get value
    # If you are doing a query, this part is not relevant
    foreach($years as $year) {
        # Determine year matches for year 1 and 2
        if($year[0] == $year_1) {
            $y1 = $year[1];
        }
        if($year[0] == $year_2) {
            $y2 = $year[1];
        }
    }
    # Determine if the years are larger or smaller from year before
    $larger =   ($y1 > $y2);
    # Divide
    $total = ($larger)? ($y2/$y1) : ($y1/$y2);
    # Write the percentage with a plus or minus
    $percent    =   (($larger)? '-':'+').round($total*100,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'%';
    # The difference in numbers
    $diff       =   ($larger)? ($y1 - $y2) : ($y2 - $y1);
    # Show both results
    print_r(array(
        'percent'=>$percent,
        'diff'=>(($larger)? '-':'+').$diff
    ));
}
```

With 1790 and 1800, what I have should give you:

```
Array
(
    [percent] => +75.03%
    [diff] => +1307417
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my post for clarification and my coding.  Basically if a user chooses 1790 and 1800... i want the PHP to handle this and subtract:  1800 - 1790 which means it will actually subtract the values associated in its array as follows: 5236631 - 3929214 and the print will give the value of that as 1307417..i hope this makes sense.

Comment: This worked! Also, i was able to print the values and such. Now my question is... if its positive, can i have it print automatically
"The population increased by (answer)" and have this highlighted in green
And if its negative to print
"The population decreased by(answer)" and have this highlighted in red?

Comment: Sure, why not? That value is `$diff` and you use `$larger` to determine plus or minus, so yeah between those two things you can write what you want.

Comment: If what I have written was helpful and answered your question, which it sounds like it did, please check mark answered so the community knows it's solved.